# Ubuntu kernel 4.4.0-34 causing black screen on boot

Tags: boot, 16.04, kernel, graphics

I have been using Ubuntu for more than 6 years now, but never experienced such a problem. I'm currently on 16.04 LTS and my kernel was recently upgraded. After selecting the default option on GRUB, the display simply goes. My monitor displays `No Signal`. I can still hear the sound when the login screen comes up, so I know the OS is working. Something with the graphics driver with kernel compatibility might be causing the issue. Any ideas how to fix this?

Currently, I select the 'Advanced options' from GRUB and select the kernel version 4.4.0-31 and I can use the machine without any problem.

Please let me know if any other details are needed and I'll update the question with the information.

**EDIT:**

As per the comment, output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` is as follows:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Integrated Graphics (rev 06)
    DeviceName:  Onboard IGD
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Skylake I
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 i have added the information..